# DateTime with timezone in ASP MVC Web API + EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-web-api, timezone

I am using ASP MVC Web API + EF and my clients are getting DateTime without information about timezone. I was trying to setup settings in WebApiConfig but without success:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling 
= DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

The only one way is working for me: to create new instance of DateTime with DateTimeKind.Local:

```
    public IEnumerable<ClientDto> Execute()
    {
        var clients = this.DbContext.Clients.Select(
            m => new ClientDto
        {
            Id = m.Id,
            NotificationSendingTime = m.NotificationSendingTime,
            . . .
        }).ToList();

        clients.ForEach(m => m.NotificationSendingTime = 
            m.NotificationSendingTime.HasValue 
            ? new DateTime(m.NotificationSendingTime.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local) 
            : m.NotificationSendingTime);

        return clients;
    }
```

But in this case I have to use .ToList() and set for each item new DateTime with timezone.

How can I setup WebApi or EF to add information about timezone automatically? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

It seems I've found solution.
My html:

```
<!-- Timepicker -->
<input id="notificationSendingTime"
       name="notificationSendingTime"
       type="text"
       class="form-control"
       data-ng-model="notificationSendingTime"
       bs-timepicker
       data-time-format="HH:mm"
       data-time-type="date"
       data-length="1" data-minute-step="30"
       data-arrow-behavior="picker" />

<!-- Timezone -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default full-width time-zone" ng-model="formData.TimeZoneId"
        data-html="1" data-animation="" placeholder="Time Zone..."
        ng-options="timeZone.Id as timeZone.FriendlyName for timeZone in timeZones" bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

My ClientDto:

```
public class ClientDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NotificationSendingTime { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? NotificationSendingTimeOffset
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.NotificationSendingTime.HasValue)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.TimeZoneId) ? "Greenwich Standard Time" : this.TimeZoneId);
            var offset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(this.NotificationSendingTime.Value, timeZoneInfo);
            return offset;
        }
    }
    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
}
```

Updating of client on server-side:

```
if (command.CommandArg.NotificationSendingTime.HasValue)
{
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.CommandArg.TimeZoneId) ? "Greenwich Standard Time" : command.CommandArg.TimeZoneId);
    var utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(command.CommandArg.NotificationSendingTime.Value, timeZoneInfo);
    command.CommandArg.NotificationSendingTime = utc.Date + new TimeSpan(utc.Hour, 0, 0);
}

client.NotificationSendingTime = command.CommandArg.NotificationSendingTime;
client.TimeZoneId = command.CommandArg.TimeZoneId;

this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In my angularJS controller after fetching the data:

```
$scope.notificationSendingTime = $scope.formData.NotificationSendingTimeOffset;
```

In my angularJS controller before submitting the data:

```
    $scope.formData.NotificationSendingTime 
= $filter('date')($scope.notificationSendingTime, 'HH:mm');
```

The timepicker works well in all browsers! Thanks.

Comment: If there any reason why you don't do: `NotificantionSendingTime = m.NotificationSendingTime.ToLocalTime()`, i.e. convert in your `Select` using [the `DateTime.ToLocalTime` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Alex, When I use .ToLocalTime() in select I get the following exception:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToLocalTime()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: oh yes of course, you are right, it would become part of the query.

Comment: What data type you are using in DB for storing date field? In your JSON do you want dates to be formatted like `2015-04-27T00:05:00+03:00`?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov, data type in DB is datetime in format like 2015-04-22 08:00:00.000. Yes, I want to add information about timezone in my JSON.

Comment: In my DB table I have column TimeZoneId in which timezone is stored in format like 'FLE Standard Time', 'Hawaiian Standard Time'. And this timezone information should be added to my DateTime. As I understand, client-side is the best place to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing time zone info in separate column I think it's will not be simple to make EF do conversion stuff. I suggested to put this functionality in model itself. For this simple example DTO looks like a good candidate:

```
[DataContract]
public class Client
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CreatedTimeZoneId { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDto
{
    private readonly Client _client;

    public ClientDto(Client client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset Created
    {
        get
        {
            //TODO: Should be moved in separate helper method.
            var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(_client.CreatedTimeZoneId);
            return new DateTimeOffset(_client.Created, timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

By using `DateTimeOffset` type you are freeing yourself from worrying about time zone handling. JSON.NET is working well with this type:

```
// Simulate DB call
var clients = new List<Client>
{
    new Client
    {
        Created = new DateTime(2015, 4, 27, 11, 48, 22, DateTimeKind.Unspecified),
        CreatedTimeZoneId = "FLE Standard Time"
    }
};

var clientDtos = clients.Select(client => new ClientDto(client));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientDtos);
```

The resulting JSON will be:

```
[{"Created":"2015-04-27T11:48:22+02:00"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, good idea, but I get 'The UTC Offset of the local dateTime parameter does not match the offset argument.' exception when I create new instance of DateTimeOffset in such way.

Comment: Can you write an example of date and timezone that throws exception?

Comment: I've found whole blog http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2012/06/14/timezone-api/